# How to stop foreground service from NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, intentservice, foreground-service

I am starting a foreground service from a Intentservice in my android app, service get started with notification. This is how i am starting service:

```html
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationforegroundService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I am listening to a particular app's notification in NotificationListenerService, when that notification is removed i am stoping the foreground service, but foreground service is still running. This is how i am stopping the foreground service:

```html
stopForeground(false);
stopService(new Intent(RemoteViewNotificationReaderService.this, NavigationforegroundService.class));
```

I could not find any clue why the service is not stopping as the documentation also suggest using stopService() or stopSelf() methods. Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong or what is the correct way to stop the service from another service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please write below code for stoping forground service.

From your service call `stopForeground(true)` and then `stopSelf()`

to stop your forground service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to stop the service in Another service.